# Java Swing. Изменение размера ярлыка в JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing

Доброго времени суток.

Собственно,как изменить ширину и высоту ярлыков в JTabbedPane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через метод JTabbedPane setTabComponentAt(int index, Component component)  можно установить свой компонент для отрисовки заголовка таба, например, JLabel с нужными параметрами. Единственное, что нужно это проделывать со всеми табами.

```
tabbedPane.setTabComponentAt(0, new JLabel("Tab"))
```

Comment: Элемент этот метод заменяет,но,почему-то,размер не меняется. Привожу код:

`Settings_Category = new JTabbedPane();
Settings_Category.setSize(width,height-56);
Settings_Category.setLocation(0,0);
Settings_Category.addTab("",Settings_Category_Graphic);
Category_Graphic_Tab = new JLabel(word_graphic);
Settings_Category_Graphic_Tab.setSize(width/4,50);
Settings_Category_Graphic_Tab.setLocation(0,0);
Settings_Category.setTabComponentAt(0,Settings_Category_Graphic_Tab);
Settings_Category_Graphic = new JPanel();`

Comment: Попробуйте *setPreferredSize* т.е. Settings_Category_Graphic_Tab.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width/4,50));

Comment: Исправил. Работает!